# Cursors in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursors, charindex

I have tried a lot of code but it has been useless.

So, what I need is to set a cursor for a table that only has a complete name:

```
create database DB01

use DB01

create table Clients
(
     complete_name varchar(50)
)

insert into Clients 
values ('Ralph Van Beethoven')
```

No problem with that.

Now, I have another database in which I have to separate my name into Name, First Last Name and Second Last Name so it has to be like this:

- Name: Ralph
- First Last Name: Van
- Second Last Name: Beethoven

Code:

```
create database DB02

use DB02

create table Clients_Details
(
     Name varchar(50),
     First_Last_Name varchar(50),
     Second_Last_Name varchar(50)
)
```

Here come the real thing. I need a cursor to split up the complete name from DB01 and insert it into DB02, I have this code:

```
Declare @name as varchar(50)
Declare cClients cursor for Select complete_name from Clients

Declare @temporal table 
(
    tName varchar(50),
    tFLName varchar(50),
    tSLName varchar(50)
)

Open cClients

Fetch cClients into @name

While (@@fetch_status = 0 )
Begin
    Insert into @temporal
        Select 
            case charindex(' ', @name) 
               when 0 then @name 
               else left(@nname, charindex(' ', @name) - 1) 
            end as tFLName,   
            case charindex(' ', @name) 
               when 0 then null 
               else right(@nname, len(@name) - charindex(' ', @nombre)) 
            end as tSLName
        from 
            Clients

        Insert into BD02.dbo.Clients_Details 
            select tName, tFLName, tSLName 
            from @temporal

    Fetch cClientes into @namecursor
End

Close cClients
Deallocate cClients
```

It throws an error

> The name of the column or the specified column do not match with the definition

so I'm guessing that my mistake is in the `charindex` because it only saves the First Last Name and Second Last Name but I'm not quite sure of what to do now.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Why do you need a cursor here at all? From what you posted this should be a single insert statement.

Comment: I have inserted my complete name "Ralph Van Beethoven" and I need to plit it up into:

Name: Ralph
First Last Name: Van
Second Last Name: Beethoven

Comment: Yeah, i now that with the charindex i can do it BUT my professor what a cursor for the case that i have a lot of names in the table Clients. For example: If I had all of your names stored in the table Clients what my professor says is that with a cursor I can split the names row by row and save them in the table Clients_Details in the other Database.

Comment: Gosh I wish these professors would stop teaching horribly inefficient loop based sql. It takes years to get people to change their thinking into set based operations. No offense to your professor doing this in a cursor is like driving a Porsche but first taking off two spark plug wires just to make sure it doesn't go too fast. Now that you learned this for your professor you should immediately forget that cursors exist.

Comment: If you have to work with cursor, I'd recommend to: 1) define it like a regular variable `declare @cClients cursor`, 2) setup it with option `FAST_FORWARD` since you don't need to scroll it backwards and don't need it to reflect changes to source table 3) stop referencing source table `Clients` from within a loop since you already fetched value(s) into variable(s) (besides, you have error there - no `where` clause in `insert-select`) 4) and I'd say that the main idea of using table variable is to postpone changes to remote table, to apply all changes by a single insert after cursor ends

Comment: right now existence of `@temporal` variable has no sense at all 5) you should always define column list in `insert` statements - you are receiving error because you are trying to insert 2 columns into the table (`@temporal`) which has 3 columns and none of 'em allows NULLs; probably you have same error on second insert to remote table because columns are not defined in that statement too.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you don't need cursor to do this

```
Insert into BD02.dbo.Clients_Details(tName,tFLName,tSLName)
SELECT NAME= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(complete_name), ' ', '.'), 1)),
       First_Last_Name= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(complete_name), ' ', '.'), 2)),
       Second_Last_Name= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(complete_name), ' ', '.'), 3))
FROM   Clients
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ NAME  ║ First_Last_Name ║ Second_Last_Name ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Ralph ║ Van             ║ Beethoven        ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

For your professor(**Not recommended**)

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE cClients CURSOR FOR
  SELECT complete_name
  FROM   Clients

OPEN cClients
FETCH cClients INTO @name

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Clients_Details
      SELECT NAME= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(@name), ' ', '.'), 1)),
             First_Last_Name= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)),
             Second_Last_Name= Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(@name), ' ', '.'), 3))

      FETCH cClients INTO @name
  END

CLOSE cClients

DEALLOCATE cClients
```

Comment: I <3 u. Thanks a lot. I now that I don't need a cursor but my professor wants me to do this with a curso. It works, I really really f*cking love you :3

Answer (score 1):

I have a split function that goes all the way back to my SQL Server 2000 days...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Split] 
    (
        @str_in VARCHAR(8000),
        @separator VARCHAR(4)
    )
RETURNS @strtable TABLE (pos int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @Occurrences INT,
    @Counter INT,
    @tmpStr VARCHAR(8000)

    SET @Counter = 0
    IF SUBSTRING(@str_in,LEN(@str_in),1) <> @separator 
    SET @str_in = @str_in + @separator
    SET @Occurrences = (DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@str_in,@separator,@separator+'#')) - DATALENGTH(@str_in))/ DATALENGTH(@separator)
    SET @tmpStr = @str_in
    WHILE @Counter <= @Occurrences 
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        INSERT INTO @strtable
        VALUES  (@Counter, SUBSTRING(@tmpStr, 1, CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr) - 1))
        SET @tmpStr = SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)+1,8000)
        IF DATALENGTH(@tmpStr) = 0
        BREAK
    END
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Of all the possible splitters this is the worst from a performance standpoint. Here are several far better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: That makes me sad. The function above has never brought my servers/websites to their knees. Also, remember that this was my solution back when we were using SQL Server 2000; and all the fancy functionality that your article discusses wasn't available.

Comment: I understand it is an old function. Much like everything else in sql server, the newer version offer many better alternatives to the way we did them in the past. :)

Comment: CLR is the bomb! 
Off topic: However, I'm a single developer responsible for many web-based apps and websites. The time it takes to deploy CLR procedures and functions vs writing pure T-SQL isn't worth the performance gains - but that's just me. In my environment, I can usually avoid stored procs and UFD's.

Comment: I don't use a CLR splitter for much the same reason. My preference actually is this one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Aaron mentions it in his article but the version posted there is NOT the same as the original. He had to change it to use varchar(max) which kills the performance. This one is an inline table valued function and is super fast as long as you don't have to pass string longer than 8k.

Comment: I love these articles with the performance graphs! If your database server is being bogged down from manipulating data before it leaves, then there is a design flaw in the system.  Database servers should be used to STORE data, not process it. :)

Comment: Agreed and splitting strings is the exact design flaw being discussed. It is however incredibly common. Hence the need for these types of things.

Comment: True dat, my brutha.